# "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] " - when trying to install any python package

Tags: python, windows, pip

When running "pip install command" on my windows 10, I am always getting such a response:

> ERROR: Error [WinError 225] Operation failed because file contains a
> virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python
> setup.py egg_info

I tried with running cmd/powershell as administrator and it doesn't help as well.
I will be very pleased with any proposed solution.

Comment: Can you give us an exact command that fails? (with a real package name). And also, could you run it with `-v` (`pip install package -v`) to get more info?